# jQuery ajax chaining doesn't wait for previous call to finish

Tags: jquery, ajax

Apologies, I'm sure this has been answered numerous times before, but be it my general slowness or my learning disability, I can't make any sense of the solutions I've googled, and I've been trying for some days.

```
getAjax1()
  .then(getAjax2())
  .then(nonAjax())
  .catch(() => {});

function getAjax1() {
  return $.ajax({
    //
  }).done(
    //
  ).fail(
    //
  )
}

function getAjax2() {
  return $.ajax({
    //
  }).done(
    //
  ).fail(
    //
  )
}

function nonAjax() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some things with the results of getAjax1() and getAjax2().
    // Has some async calls.
  });
}
```

From what I understand, the code above is basically what I'd do if I have a function nonAjax() that relies on the results of getAjax1() and getAjax2(), which have to be executed in that order.

But, that's not what happens.  All 3 function calls execute before any of the ajax calls parse a response.  And this is where I'm stuck.

I can't callback nest this because it's not always the case that getAjax2() is called after getAjax1(), sometimes it's getAjax3() instead.

Comment: You're *invoking* the function immediately, when you should be just *passing* the function to `.then`. The `.then`'s internals will then invoke it when the prior Promise is done

Comment: Still doesn't wait for ajax return when I have for example .then(() => {getAjax2()}), but I'm probably messing some silly thing up in the code that doesn't match the example.  I'll have to spend some time trying to figure out what I messed up.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now you're not returning the call - the function is returning `undefined`. Use `.then(getAjax2)`

Comment: Oh, now that works, thanks!  I don't know why I didn't make that connection, it works the same way in PHP basically.